# Write down sum of nth term?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given series is $$1, \ \frac{2}{4}, \ \frac{3}{4^2},\ \frac{4}{4^3}....$$

Write down Sum of $n$-th term.

Hence write sum to infinity

So $a$ is $1$ but what's the common ratio? Is this even a G.P? Since there is a sum to infinity it has to be G.P.right?

Comment: Is the fourth term supposed to be 4/4^3?

Comment: Ya sorry but how to write Sn?

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetico-geometric_series

Comment: This is Arithmetico Geometric Series.

Comment: Hi Lim, did you ever see this before: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, no the ratio is not common from one pair of terms to the next. To work this out, simply calculate the ratio of the first two terms and then the ratio of the 2nd pair of terms.

Answer (score 1):

Making your problem more general, the terms look to be $$1 \qquad 2x  \qquad 3x^2  \qquad 4x^3  \qquad \dots$$ where $x=\frac 14$.

So $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n i x^{i-1}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n  x^{i}\right)'$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it